# New columns with other columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
 > df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["2002-01-12","2002-01-12","2002-01-12","2002-01-13","2002-01-13","2002-01-13","2002-01-16","2002-01-16","2002-01-16"], "B": ["12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00","11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00"], "C": [ 3,19, 15, 6, 1, 5, 3, 12, 8]})

           A         B   C
0 2002-01-12  12:00:00   3
1 2002-01-12  13:00:00  19
2 2002-01-12  14:00:00  15
3 2002-01-13  11:00:00   6
4 2002-01-13  12:00:00   1
5 2002-01-13  13:00:00   5
6 2002-01-16  10:00:00   3
7 2002-01-16  11:00:00  12
8 2002-01-16  12:00:00   8
```

I want to create a new `df['D']` and `df['E']` with next conditions, per each `A` group:

- `df['D']`: Take `C` values of day before (respect `A` group) when `B == 12:00:00`
- `df['E']`: Take `C` values mean of day before (respect `A` group).

Output should be:

```
           A         B   C    D     E
0 2002-01-12  12:00:00   3    0     0
1 2002-01-12  13:00:00  19    0     0
2 2002-01-12  14:00:00  15    0     0
3 2002-01-13  11:00:00   6    3  12.3
4 2002-01-13  12:00:00   1    3  12.3
5 2002-01-13  13:00:00   5    3  12.3
6 2002-01-16  10:00:00   3    1   4.0
7 2002-01-16  11:00:00  12    1   4.0
8 2002-01-16  12:00:00   8    1   4.0
```

Comment: For each day exist `12:00:00` values?

Comment: Yes, it does exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create for each day helper `Series`, for previous day add [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to new column, last replace `NaN`s by `fillna`:

```
a = df[df['B'].eq('12:00:00')].set_index('A')['C'].shift(1)
b = df.groupby('A')['C'].mean().shift(1)

df['D'] = df['A'].map(a)
df['E'] = df['A'].map(b)
df[['D','E']] = df[['D','E']].fillna(0)
print (df)
           A         B   C    D          E
0 2002-01-12  12:00:00   3  0.0   0.000000
1 2002-01-12  13:00:00  19  0.0   0.000000
2 2002-01-12  14:00:00  15  0.0   0.000000
3 2002-01-13  11:00:00   6  3.0  12.333333
4 2002-01-13  12:00:00   1  3.0  12.333333
5 2002-01-13  13:00:00   5  3.0  12.333333
6 2002-01-16  10:00:00   3  1.0   4.000000
7 2002-01-16  11:00:00  12  1.0   4.000000
8 2002-01-16  12:00:00   8  1.0   4.000000
```

Comment: Any alternative to `df[df['B'].eq('12:00:00')].set_index('A')['C'].shift(1)` ?
I get next error when executing: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: @Tie_24 - It means duplicated values of column A. You can check it by `df1=df[df['B'].eq('12:00:00')]` and `print(df1[df1.A.duplicated(keep=False)])`. Possible solutions are remove dupes and keeo first value like `df[df['B'].eq('12:00:00')].drop_duplicates(subset=['A']).set_index('A')['C'].shift(1)` or aggregate duplicates like `df[df['B'].eq('12:00:00')].groupby('A')['C'].mean().shift(1)`

Comment: @Tie_24 - glad can help your interesting questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a more robust one, but works:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

df['D'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: df[(df['A']==(x + pd.DateOffset(-1)))&(df['B']=='12:00:00')]['C'].mean()).fillna(0)
df['E'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: df[df['A']==(x + pd.DateOffset(-1))]['C'].mean()).fillna(0)
```